# git-svn rejected Basic challenge now that VPN is required

Tags: linux, git, svn, git-svn, vpn

I have been using [git-svn](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html) for a few months now as an interface to the SVN repository for my company.

However, about a week ago my company changed their policy such that SVN is only reachable if connected by way of Cisco VPN.

I have no trouble connecting to VPN on my Linux Mint VM (which is where I do my coding), but I am now no longer able to pass authentication when I, for example, run `git svn dcommit` to checkin code changes.

I have tried:

- `rm -rf ~/.subversion`, to get rid of any saved SVN authentication credentials and force it to take new ones, but this seems to have no effect, nor does it ever prompt me for fresh credentials, surprisingly.
- starting in a freshly created directory and running `git svn clone` to initiate a new link to the SVN repository, but with the same authentication failures.

Here is what I see when running `git svn dcommit` or `git svn clone`:

```
$ git svn dcommit
Committing to https://<redacted>:2443/svn/LS/branches/PRODUCTION-SUPPORT-1/ls-policygen ...
WARNING: gnome-keyring:: couldn't connect to: /tmp/keyring-wCQwzG/pkcs11: No such file or directory
Authorization failed: OPTIONS of 'https://<redacted>:2443/svn/LS/branches/PRODUCTION-SUPPORT-1/ls-policygen': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: ignored NTLM challenge, rejected Basic challenge (https://<redacted>:2443) at /usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 943
```

The `gnome-keyring` warning has always been present, and never stopped commits before VPN was required.

Comment: Did you try: mv ~/.git ~/.git.bak ?
Since you use git-svn the config likelly can be into ~/.git and not ~/.subversion.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440685/what-is-the-cause-and-solution-to-svn-could-not-authenticate-to-server-rejecte , basic auth can fail due to the password containing non-ASCII characters.  Does your password contain such characters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what ports need to be open for svn tortoise to authenticate (clear text) and commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249097/what-ports-need-to-be-open-for-svn-tortoise-to-authenticate-clear-text-and-com)

Comment: Cisco's SSL VPN may be blocking port 2443.  Are you sure they have not provided a proxy (new URL) for the SVN repository on port 443 or port 80?  If you were to checkout the SVN repository without using GIT SVN, what would you type?  Does that work?

Comment: Try to connect to the remote server using telnet or netcat. Or just a browser, since it's HTTPS.

Comment: Can you connect to the server using subversion instead of git-svn?

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this snipped from your error code:

```
Authorization failed: OPTIONS of 'https://<redacted>:2443/svn/LS/branches/PRODUCTION-SUPPORT-1/ls-policygen': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: ignored NTLM challenge, rejected Basic challenge (https://<redacted>:2443) at /usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 943
```

specially at this part: **Could not authenticate to server: ignored NTLM challenge**

It looks like your company also changed autentication methods too.

Take a look at: [Does git clone work through NTLM proxies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783659/does-git-clone-work-through-ntlm-proxies)

I would take this steps:

1. connect to your repository within your browser
2. try to connect with another user account - probably you have some cache files in your home directory
3. configure git or even svn according to NTLM auth

Good Luck,

LEslie