# Collabnet Subversion Authentication with Active Directory block some user..!

Tags: authentication, svn, active-directory, collabnet

Now, I am trying to use Collabnet Subversion Edge authentication with Active Directory. At that, I found a problem.

Some user in AD can enter into Collabnet and some are not. Actually, all user in my AD server are created by script. So, all configuration except username and password are equal. But some cannot enter into Collabnet. So, I check the collabnet log. It shows "Password Mismatch" error for all invalid user. But we type the right password.

And then we test by changing account password. No changes. Then, I created a new account and log-in into Collabnet. It is OK. I don't know what should do.

Summary, In my authentication with AD, Newly Created user can log-in into Collabnet, Old User who success first time can also log-in and some user are always "Password Mismatch" even I type right password. I tried every possible way what I think, but It is not work.

Anyone faced like this one? Someone Help me. Thanks.

Comment: Any special characters in your AD user accounts' passwords?

Comment: Yes, our rule is all account's password must contain one special character. Some account can login and some are not. Can you help me?

Comment: I guess that your case is related to http://stackoverflow.com/a/13741257/761095. Either don't use special characters in passwords or implement single sign-on on the server.

Comment: No, I tried. But it is not.